# Putting video clipp at background of a slide

Tags: beamer, pdftex, backgrounds, slideshow

i want to put a video clip at **background** of a slide and add some text lines/bullet points.
Is there any way to do so in Latex?

Comment: Won't be possible, I am afraid. In PDF, video rendering is plugin-based and the activated plugin floats on top of normal page content (text, images), and thus obscuring it.

Comment: Okay, thank you sir